# Windows Update for IoT Core using Powershell

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windows-update, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to manually perform Windows Update for my IoT core device (RPI 3). I tried doing so using the device portal but for some reason it fails.

Hence I am trying to perform the update by connecting via Powershell.

What are the steps I should follow ?

Comment: Do you have [Windows 10 IoT Core Pro](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/createiotcorepro)? What's the version of your Windows IoT core?

Comment: I got the Raspberry Pi 3 and it came installed with it.

Comment: @dparkar Were you able to solve it?